# Clicking the send button

Tags: python, thunderbird

```
def mailto_url(to=None,subject=None,body=None,cc=None):
    url = "mailto:" + urllib.quote(to.strip(),"@,")
    sep = "?"
    if cc:
        url+= sep + "cc=" + urllib.quote(cc,"@,")
        sep = "&"
    if subject:
        url+= sep + "subject=" + urllib.quote(subject,"")
        sep = "&"
    if body:
        body="\r\n".join(body.splitlines())
        url+= sep + "body=" + urllib.quote(body,"")
        sep = "&"
    return url
import urllib
import webbrowser
url = mailto_url('email address', 'subject', 'message body')
webbrowser.open(url,new=1)
```

I have the above code to bring out the default email client. But I need to automate to send the email. Is there any way to use the script to press on the "Send" button?

Comment: Why are you trying to automate a GUI mail client instead of just sending the message with Python? At minimum, you'll almost certainly need to know what OS and email client your user is using. On a Mac, for example, it's fairly easy to do this with Applescript.

Comment: The script is only for me though. So you are saying i need to understand the GUI of the mail client? And is it possible to run Applescript on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the message to be sent through the GUI client?  The client is designed as an interface between the email protocols and a human with a mouse and keyboard, not your Python script.

You can use the [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) module to send email directly from Python.  If you need a record of it in Thunderbird, perhaps you could cc it to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want/need to do this with Python, there's a Windows GUI automation tool called [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Save this in file like sendmail.vbs

```
dim sendKeyObj
Set sendKeyObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sendKeyObj.SendKeys "^{ENTER}"
```

and use python to run this script from the command line with

```
cscript /nologo "C:\path\to\sendmail.vbs"
```

So, that would be in Python

```
import os
os.system("cscript /nologo \"C:\\path\\to\\sendmail.vbs\"")
```

(I hope I got the escaping right). You might want to use the subprocess module instead of os. The VBScript really only presses the Send button in Thunderbird. I think this only works if the e-mail can actually appear in a new window in front of everything else. I use this set-up for sending invoices and the like.